# PrestaShop images not showing when friendly-URL is switched on

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

After an installing a new SSL certificate and changing the PHP version from 5.x to 7.1.28 product images are not shown in the frontend anymore, Chrome dev tools show a 404 error for the image files. 
They are visible in the backend under product catalog.

It looks like if the image directory is missing, i.e. something like /home-default/ because in the HTML code the image file is supposed to be directly on the document root directory, which obviously is wrong.

When I switch off "Friendly URL" the images are shown.
What I tried so far:

1. Deleted .htaccess, switched Friendly URL to on to regenerate the .htaccess
2. Emptied cache and regenerated the image thumbnails
3. Switched back to PHP 5.4
4. Added AllowOverride All to the vhost config

Nothing helps. On the server is another PrestaShop installation, running same PrestaShop version 1.6.18 also under PHP 7.1.28, there the "Friendly URL" works fine.

I must say I have no clue where to look after this problem.

Comment: Hi @Harry, Are you using Nginx or Apache? Can you post a screenshot of the "Network" tab from the web-browser console?

Comment: Hi @Bruno, Apache with nginx as reverse proxy. Here are the screenshots:

with friendly url on: https://prnt.sc/nm0p9i
with friendly url off: https://prnt.sc/nm0pum

Comment: Are your PrestaShop rewrite rules defined in Nginx or Apache? Here's an example for Nginx: https://gist.github.com/julienbourdeau/79961e9caa4263e9e34d2d056948d335 which includes rules for image URLs as well. Also, I'd recommend dropping Apache and simply go with Nginx + PHP-FPM 7.3.x using FastCGI to get the best performance. I hope this helps, if not, try to ping me in the StackOverflow PrestaShop chat room.

Comment: @BrunoLeveque we are using Apache, the rewrites work, the only problem are the images. We use Apache 7.1.28 as FPM module using op_cache and nginx to server static content, that gives the best performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After spending some time with @Harry, debugging his configuration, we found the solution and I'm sure this will help many others.

@Harry was using a combo with Nginx + Apache.

1. We checked his PrestaShop .htaccess file and made sure RewriteEngine was on and triggered properly (e.g. the pages were properly rewrited, only the images were not) - everything was OK.
2. We tried to write ourselves a basic RewriteRule to redirect a .jpg and it did not work, showing an Nginx 404 page.
3. We came to the conclusion Nginx was handling all the static content (JS, CSS, JPEG, etc.) and not forwarding it to Apache.

**Solution**

We removed this part from the Nginx configuration:

```
location ~ ^/(.*\.(ac3|avi|bmp|bz2|cue|dat|doc|docx|dts|eot|exe|flv|gz|htm|html|img|iso|jpeg|mkv|mp3|mp4|mpeg|mpg|ogg|ppt|pptx|qt|rar|rm|swf|tar|tgz|ttf|txt|wav|xls|xlsx|zip))$ {
                try_files $uri @fallback;
}
```

As a general advice, I would suggest not using Apache+Nginx, PrestaShop works very well with Nginx+PHP-FPM already and you will get great performances.

If you choose this solution, don't forget to set your PrestaShop rewrite rules directly in Nginx ([Example](https://gist.github.com/julienbourdeau/79961e9caa4263e9e34d2d056948d335)).

Answer (score 0):

You can bypass your main/default Nginx conf params to prevent conflicting image htaccess rule for your P.S domain. (Otherwise default conf params block the P.S image showing .htaccess rule.)

**Basicly:**

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
}

# Images.
rewrite ^/(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$1$2.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$1$2$3.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$1$2$3$4.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$1$2$3$4$5.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$1$2$3$4$5$6.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8.jpg last;
rewrite ^/(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(\d)(-[\w-]+)?/.+\.jpg$ /img/p/$1/$2/$3/$4/$5/$6/$7/$8/$1$2$3$4$5$6$7$8$9.jpg last;
rewrite ^/c/([\w.-]+)/.+\.jpg$ /img/c/$1.jpg last;

# AlphaImageLoader for IE and FancyBox.
rewrite ^images_ie/?([^/]+)\.(gif|jpe?g|png)$ js/jquery/plugins/fancybox/images/$1.$2 last;
```